# Number of nops to prevent pipeline harzards

Tags: computer-science, mips, cpu-architecture

For the following code segment, I am required to insert a minimum number of nops to resolve all potential pipeline hazards.

```
lw $t3, 4($t5)
beq $t2, $t3, -2
addi $t2, $t2, 1
```

And the solution I proposed is

```
lw $t3, 4($t5)           
beq $t2, $t3, -2 
addi $t2, $t2, 1
NOP     
NOP
```

However, I am not quite sure above the answer above, so anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the only concern here is to ensure that `$t2` gets the correct value ($t2 + 1) before the `beq` is hit in the next cycle. The answer really depends on how many cycles it takes to write the value of `$t2` back to memory or the cache - you've omitted that detail, but assuming that you only have a 3-stage pipeline and every operation takes 1 cycle I believe that even a single NOP can work:

1. in cycle 0, `lw` enters the pipeline as the value from the `addi` becomes available
2. in cycle 1, `beq` compares the value of `$t3` and `$t2`, which became available from the last cycle

It's impossible to say if your implementation supports this type of forwarding. The safe bet would be two NOPs but you've left out quite a few details, and I don't have enough rep yet to leave a comment for clarification :( Hope this helps.